# statement of strong cayley's theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Strong Cayley's Theorem as stated in Topics in Algebra by I.N. Herstein :

*If G is a group, H a subgroup of G, and S is the set of all right cosets of H in G, then there is a homomorphism $ \theta $ of G into A(S) and the kernel of $ \theta $ is the largest normal subgroup of G which is contained in H*

*(note1: For any set $ S $ , we define $ A(S) $ as the set of all bijections on S)

*(note2: Mapping which is not onto is called an into mapping)

[For the proof, please refer to page 85, 86 of the pdf](https://marinazahara22.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/i-n-herstein-topics-in-algebra-2nd-edition-1975-wiley-international-editions-john-wiley-and-sons-wie-1975.pdf)

My question is: how can we say that the above mentioned homomorphism $ \theta $ is into?

Can anyone please explain?

Comment: We can't. The map may be surjective. I suspect that the correct nomenclature is that a map that is surjective is called "onto", and a map that is *not necessarily* surjective is called "into". There are several instances in which the map is onto: e.g., if $[G:H]\leq 2$; if for another example, take $G=S_{n+1}$, $n\geq 4$, $H$ the subgroup of all permutations that fix $n+1$. Then the largest normal subgroup contained in $H$ is trivial, and the morphism you get is an isomorphism, since it is an injective map into a group of order $(n+1)!$, same as $|G|$.

Comment: You've got the definition of "into" incorrect. There is no such definition in the PDF. A map from $A$ into $B$ is just a function/map with domain $A$ and codomain $B$; it may be surjective or not. For example, look at the definition in pp 12 (page 25 of the PDF), that reads: "The mapping $\tau$ of $S$ **into** $T$ is said to be *onto* $T$ if given any $t\in T$ there exists an element $s\in S$ such that $t=s\tau$" [boldface added]. The statement would be nonsensical  if "into" really meant "definitely not onto".

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks for the first example. But for the second one, if $H$ is the subgroup of all permutations that fix $n+1$ then $H \cong S_{n}$ and hence $A_{n} \lhd H$. Can you please explain how did you conclude that $ H $ is simple?

Comment: You are looking for the largest subgroup of $H$ that is normal **in $G$**, not in $H$. The copy of $A_n$ that is sitting inside of $H$ is normal in $H$, but **not** in $G$; it cannot be the kernel of homomorphism with domain $G$. I did not claim $H$ was simple, I said it did not contain any nontrivial normal subgroups **of $G$**.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for your time @ArturoMagidin